# Why is RestClient throwing null pointer exception when trying to post a JSON data to a restful web service?

Tags: json, rest, groovy

I am trying to use the RESTClient class to do a post to a RESTful web service. I am getting an NPE at setBody in groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.

My code is

```
postParam = [
  sourceAccountNo         : fundTransfer.fromAccount.accountNumber,
  sourceBankCode          : fundTransfer.fromAccount.bank.bankCode,
  destinationBankCode     : fundTransfer.toAccount.bank.bankCode,
  destinationBankAccountNo: fundTransfer.toAccount.accountNumber,
  amount                  : fundTransfer.amount,
  narrationOne            : fundTransfer.note,
  uniqueId                : fundTransfer.uniqueId
]

String balanceTransferURL = ApplicationProperty.propertiesMap.get(ApplicationProperty.PropertyKey.BULK_BALANCE_TRANSFER_URL)
def restClient = new RESTClient(balanceTransferURL)
def restResponse = restClient.post(requestContentType:JSON,body:postParam)
```

My error log is as follows

```
message: null
    Line | Method
->> 1200 | setBody                     in groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1111 | setPropertiesFromMap        in     ''
|    946 | <init> . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    140 | post                        in groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
```

What is exactly missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks ok. Maybe on of fields taken from `fundTransfer` evaluates to null: e.g. `bank`?

Comment: No thats not my problem

Comment: which version of RESTClient are you using? and did you make sure postParam has all values and no nulls?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and figured out that it goes away when you add the requestContentType parameter:

```
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

requestContentType:JSON
```